# How do I create a SELECT statement with a list as a parameter?

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.6

## Code

The following code *only* works when the list `targets_in_sw` only has one value in it:

```
sw_current = cursor.execute("SELECT * from SOFTWARE_")
sw_current = sw_current.fetchall()
for sw_item in sw_current:
    current_software_id = sw_item[0]
    # Create Software XML Element
    sw_element = ET.SubElement(root, "Software")
    # Get all Targets for current sw_element
    targets_in_sw = cursor.execute("SELECT TARGET2 from SOFTWARE_TARGET_ WHERE SOFTWARE1=?", (current_software_id,))
    targets_in_software = targets_in_sw.fetchall()
    targets_in_software = list(chain.from_iterable(targets_in_sw))
    # Get all Target IDs for current sw_element
    current_target_IDs = cursor.execute("SELECT * from TARGET_ WHERE id_=?", targets_in_software)
    current_target_IDs = current_target_IDs.fetchall()
    ## The following line ONLY prints when my list contains one value ##
    print current_target_IDs
```

## Question

How can I change this so that I may select everything from `TARGET_` when `targets_in_software` is a list of multiple values?

**Notes:**

In case you didn't see the tags, I'm using **SQLite3**.

Here's an example of the values within `targets_in_software` while going through the loop:

```
iteration       targets_in_software
        1       [21]
        2       [28]
        3       [29]
        4       [91]
        5       [92]
        6       [94]
        7       [217]
        8       [218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228]
        9       [251]
       10       [261]
...etc.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your raw SQL query should look like this:

`SELECT val FROM table_name WHERE ref_val in ('val_one','val_two');`

So for your case, you should do:

`targets_in_sw = cursor.execute("SELECT TARGET2 from SOFTWARE_TARGET_ WHERE SOFTWARE1=(" + ",".join(targets_in_software) + ");")`

Please note that this will not protect you against SQL injection.

Comment: Shouldn't this be for my `current_target_IDs` variable? e.g. `current_target_IDs = cursor.execute("SELECT * from TARGET_ WHERE id_="( + ",".join(targets_in_software) + ");"))` ?

Comment: Also I fixed a mistake in my question - I was calling my `targets_in_sw` variable `targets_in_software` so I changed it to the latter

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how it should be

Comment: Okok, now I get the following error: `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found`  **D:**

Comment: Quick hack - .join([str(x) for x in targets_in_software])

Comment: Changed my SELECT statement to `("SELECT * from TARGET_ WHERE id_="( + ",".join([str(x) for x in targets_in_sw]) + ");"))` - Now I'm drifting away from the syntax error and instead get the error: `TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'`. Can we not use `+` like this? I think it's trying to add things instead of concatenate them, yes?

Comment: Your opening bracket for the SQL query is falling outside the string. Put it within the string like this WHERE id=(" + "."join.... instead of WHERE id="( +

Comment: I got it working correctly. I've added the working code to the end of your answer...I think I'm allowed to do that anyway **O.o**

Answer (score 1):

You can create your query this way using `IN`:

```
SELECT * from TARGET_ WHERE id IN tuple(targets_in_software)
```

This will work when `targets_in_software` has multiple values.

Comment: Hi - Could you include the syntax for the execute statement? `cursor.execute("SELECT * from TARGET_ WHERE id_ in tuple(targets_in_sw)")` gives me an error so I'm guessing my syntax is wrong

Comment: I'm using **SQLite3** if that helps

Comment: @Kimbluey try `SELECT * from TARGET_ WHERE id_ in ?", tuple(targets_in_sw)`

Comment: That looks closer to what I'm used to seeing, but I still get the following error: `OperationalError: near "?": syntax error`

Comment: @Kimbluey there must be some syntax error as it worksin sqallite :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the SQL [IN operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) with your ORM.  I don't have enough details to know what you're using.  Try `SELECT TARGET2 from SOFTWARE_TARGET_ WHERE SOFTWARE1 IN ?` or `SELECT TARGET2 from SOFTWARE_TARGET_ WHERE SOFTWARE1 IN ?` with sw_item as your parameter instead of current_software_id.

Comment: That's not the line I'm having problems with, but changing the line you have indicated to `targets_in_sw = cursor.execute("SELECT TARGET2 from SOFTWARE_TARGET_ WHERE SOFTWARE1 IN ?", (sw_item,))` gives me the error `OperationalError: near "?": syntax error`. Is that syntax correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you pass a tuple as the second parameter of execute, it will try to substitute each element of the tuple for the placeholders in the query string, for example:

```
stmt = "INSERT INTO mytable (name, id, rank) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
cursor.execute(stmt, (a, b, c))
```

creates a query where each %s is replaced by an element of the tuple.  In your case, you want to end up with a query where the entire tuple is together in one place, so you need to convert it to a string:

```
stmt = "SELECT * from TARGET_ WHERE id_ IN %s"
#convert list of ints to tuple of strings
stmt_param = str(tuple(map(str, targets_in_software)))
cursor.execute(stmt, stmt_param)
```

I think this should work, although I couldn't test it because I don't have a database to test against.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi - the line `current_target_IDs = cursor.execute("SELECT * from TARGET_ WHERE id_ IN %s", str(tuple(targets_in_sw)))` gives me a syntax error. I also tried using `?` instead of `%s` (also gave a syntax error). Is this syntax compatible with SQLite3?

Comment: It might be incompatible, I don't know.  But here's how you can find out:  create a test query with hard-coded values like this: `SELECT * from TARGET_ WHERE id_ IN (218, 219, 220)` and if that gives you an error, then SQLite3 doesn't support that type of query.

Comment: Okay, the line `current_target_IDs = cursor.execute("SELECT * from TARGET_ WHERE id_ IN (218, 219, 220)")` gives me no errors. Now what **D:**

Comment: I just realized you need to convert those numbers to strings first... I'm editing my answer.

Comment: Seems like it shouldn't make a difference since the whole tuple is being converted to a string anyway... Sorry, I don't know what else to try :(

Comment: Yea...the new piece still gives me a syntax error :( Maybe I'll try @johnwamburu 's code again with the addition of your code for converting my list of ints to tuple of strings? Does that sound like it would work?