# Python 2.6 TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str' - What is the correct syntax?

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.6

## Code

```
sw_current = cursor.execute("SELECT * from SOFTWARE_")
sw_current = sw_current.fetchall()
for sw_item in sw_current:
    current_software_id = sw_item[0]
    # Create Software XML Element
    sw_element = ET.SubElement(root, "Software")
    # Set Software attributes
    for s in range(1, len(software_attributes)):
       sw_element.set(software_attributes[s], str(sw_item[s]))
    # Get all Targets for current sw_element
    targets_in_sw = cursor.execute("SELECT TARGET2 from SOFTWARE_TARGET_ WHERE SOFTWARE1=?", (current_software_id,))
    targets_in_sw = list(chain.from_iterable(targets_in_sw.fetchall()))
    # Get all Target IDs for current sw_element
    current_target_IDs = cursor.execute("SELECT * from TARGET_ WHERE id_="( + ",".join([str(x) for x in targets_in_sw]) + ");"))
    current_target_IDs = current_target_IDs.fetchall()
```

Here is the line where the error occurs:

```
current_target_IDs = cursor.execute("SELECT * from TARGET_ WHERE id_="( + ",".join([str(x) for x in targets_in_sw]) + ");"))
                                                                        ^                                           ^
```

## Explanation

I'm trying to select everything from `TARGET_` when `targets_in_sw` is a list that may or may not have multiple values. Pleas see [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28885701/how-do-i-create-a-select-statement-with-a-list-as-a-parameter) for more information.

## Question

What is the correct syntax for the line of code with the error? What do I use in place of the `+` operand?

Comment: Note the parenthesis before the `+`.

Comment: Still using python 2.6 is bad, but using string operation to interpolate date in SQL queries is worse. Use paremetrized queries instead!

Comment: You need to use a `WHERE columname IN (id1, id2, ...)` query pattern here; you cannot simply join ids with a `id_=` SQL statement. See the duplicate, which generates enough parameters as needed.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Unfortunately using anything other than Python 2.6 is not an option...What is a parameterized query? :( Would that be like what Martijn is doing in the [duplicate answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245396/using-a-where-in-statement)?

Comment: @MartijnPieters so I would do `statement = "SELECT * from TARGET_ WHERE id_ IN ({0})".format(', '.join([str(x) for x in targets_in_sw]))` and then `current_target_IDs = cursor.execute(statement, targets_in_sw)`? I don't quite understand these :(

Comment: @Kimbluey: no, you'd insert *paramater placeholders*, so `'?'` question marks. `statement = "SELECT * from TARGET_ WHERE id_ IN ({0})".format(', '.join(['?'] * len(targets_in_sw)))`.